# How to edit/use xaml datatemplate in code

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, datatemplate

In XAML, I have:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="AgeItemTemplate">
    <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" BorderBrush="#6FBDE8">
           <TextBlock Margin="2" Text="{Binding Age}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" />
     </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

How could I use that DataTemplate in code?

[image]

I know I can create a new template and linked to a gridview column but I want to define that template in xaml. Is there any way to modify and use that dataTemplate in code behind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [findresource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findresource.aspx) method on FrameworkElement.

Comment: I am new to xaml. I placed that template inside: <Grid.Resources > on the same xaml it is not inside a dictionary. Or maybe <Grid.Resources > is a dictionary. How do I use the control dictionary of the control that I am using?

Comment: I updated My awnser with a better way :) but all controls have a resources property that is a resourcedictionary.

Answer (score 2):

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="PersonItemTemplate" x:Name="someTemplate">
            <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" BorderBrush="#6FBDE8">
                <Grid Margin="2">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="32" />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Source="Images/person.png" Width="24" Height="24" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" />
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
```

code behind:

```
template1 = (DataTemplate)FindName("someTemplate");

        linkColumn1 = new GridViewColumn
        {
            Header = "Test",
            CellTemplate = template1,
            //Width = 88,  // Comment out to set to auto

        };

        gv.Columns.Add(linkColumn1);
```

as a result I was able to duplicate a column with code:

[image]

this is helpful to populate a listview dynamically because it is harder to create the styles on code I believe.